# No viable overloaded operator for references a map

Tags: c++, xml, c++11, xml-parsing

I am trying to use a map so I can make tag names to a reference number. When I try and use it, like in this code I get the error (6 in total every time I reference map):

```
src/main.cpp:25:45: error: no viable overloaded operator[] for type
      'std::map<std::string, std::string>'
                const char* idcs = node.child_value(tagMap[3]);
```

This is the code:

```
#include "pugi/pugixml.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    pugi::xml_document doca, docb;
    std::map<std::string, pugi::xml_node> mapa, mapb;
    std::map<std::string, std::string> tagMap {{"1", "data"}, {"2", "entry"}, {"3", "id"}, {"4", "content"}};

    if (!doca.load_file("a.xml") || !docb.load_file("b.xml")) {
        std::cout << "Can't find input files";
        return 1;
    }

    for (auto& node: doca.child(tagMap[1]).children(tagMap[2])) {
        const char* id = node.child_value(tagMap[3]);
        mapa[id] = node;
    }

    for (auto& node: docb.child(tagMap[1]).children(tagMap[2])) {
        const char* idcs = node.child_value(tagMap[3]);
        if (!mapa.erase(idcs)) {
            mapb[idcs] = node;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You declare the map to use a *string* for key, not integers.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg So it should be like this ```std::map<int, std::string> tagMap```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> const char* idcs = node.child_value(tagMap[3]);
> ```

is incorrect, `tagMap` can only be indexed by keytype which is `std::string`
what you need is:

> ```
> const std::string& idcs = node.child_value(tagMap["3"]);
> ```

Comment: Sarang, quick question. Do I need to do this for this one too? ```const char* id = node.child_value(tagMap[3]);```

Comment: And, @Sarang, Do I still need to change my map to use an int as well?

Comment: you will have to change tagMap indexers to use strings. @changing map to use int- is upto how you want it

Comment: but if I change map to use int, do I still need to do what you suggest above?

Comment: nope not then, it will just work what you had earlier- just the type for map will change to  std::map<int, std::string>